# Recursive Methods for printing contents of a stack

Tags: java, recursion, methods, stack

So I want to write a method that takes a stack and prints its contents recursively without using any temporary stack and at the end of the method the stack would become empty.

Any idea on how to start ? :S

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Stack <Integer> IntegersStack = new Stack <Integer>();
  IntegersStack.push(1);
  printStack(IntegersStack);
  IntegersStack.push(2);
  printStack(IntegersStack);
  IntegersStack.push(3);
  printStack(IntegersStack);

  //now to prepare for prinitng
  IntegersStack.pop();
  printStack(IntegersStack);
  IntegersStack.pop();
  printStack(IntegersStack);
  IntegersStack.pop();
  printStack(IntegersStack);

}

public static void stackRecursive(Stack <Integer> ps) {
  if (ps.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("Sorry stack is empty");
  } else {
    System.out.printf("%d",ps);
  }
}

}
```

Eh could this work ? would the stack be empty ?

Comment: Sounds pretty straight forward, so I'm wondering if I'm missing anything. Can you share a sample stack and the result you'd like to get for it?

Comment: Stack Overflow encourages to try on your own first and provide code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Could this work I updated it ?

Comment: And it is totally ok to receive outside help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need recursion to print the contents of a stack from top to bottom, and it should look like

```
while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(stack.pop());
}
```

If you want to print it from bottom to top you can try this recursive approach:

```
private void printStack(Stack<Integer> stack) {
    if (stack.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    } else {
        int i = stack.pop();
        printStack(stack);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a method with the stack as parameter and following implementation. Take one element off and print it. Pass the stack to the method unless it is empty.